# Why is Rails not setting a cookie variable correctly when using AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cookies

When I try and set a cookie in a remote action it isn't being set correctly.

Ajax:

controller/stories:

```
def vote
    unless cookies[params[:story_id]]
        @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
        @story.rating += 1
        @story.save
        cookies[params[:story_id]] = true
    end
end
```

views/stories:

```
<% unless cookies[story.id] %>
    <%= link_to "▲", story_vote_path(story), :remote => true, :method => "put", class: :vote %>
<% end %>
```

Non-ajax:

controller/stories:

```
def vote
    unless cookies[params[:story_id]]
        @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
        @story.rating += 1
        @story.save
        cookies[params[:story_id]] = true
    end
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

views/stories:

```
<% unless cookies[story.id] %>
    <%= link_to "▲", story_vote_path(story), :method => "put", class: :vote %>
<% end %>
```

In the former code regardless of whether the link has been clicked it still appears and can be used to vote again. However in the latter the link no longer appears and you cannot vote again.
I've looked and found that the set_cookie header can be sent back from an ajax call, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What is the view being rendered after the vote action in ajax request? You'll need a js to hide the link

Comment: I understand that. However after a reload the link still appears, which the unless cookies[story.id] should be preventing.

Comment: FYI Ruby doesn't support this line: `@story.rating += 1` - you'll have to use `@story.rating = @story.rating + 1`

Comment: I wasn't sure if it'd work so I tried and it does increment the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but if you're trying to create a cookie via Ajax, wouldn't that mean you'll have to refresh the HTTP request in order to make that cookie work with Rails?

You can do several things to test this:

1. Refresh your page (& include the `cookie` in your view (to see if it's set))
2. Set a `Rails.logger.info()` command to see if the cookie is being set
3. Try another method

---

**Refresh**

```
#app/views/stories/show.html.erb
<%= cookies[story.id] %>
```

Including this code in your view will output any contents of that cookie. This means if you perform the ajax request, you can refresh the page to see if it's actually been set (& not caught by your ajax-bound code)

---

**Logger**

```
unless cookies[params[:story_id]]
    @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
    @story.increment!(:rating)

    cookies[params[:story_id]] = true
    Rails.logger.info(cookies[story.id])
end
```

This will output the cookie in the Rails log, allowing you to see if it's actually being set

---

**Ajax**

Looks like your use of cookies is somewhat inefficient. I'd prefer to use a simple `respond_to` system like this:

```
#app/controllers/stories_controller.rb
def vote
    unless cookies[params[:story_id]]
        @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
        @story.increment!(:rating)
    end
    respond_to do |format| 
        format.html { redirect_to root_url }
        format.js
    end
end

#app/views/stories/vote.js.erb
<% if @story %>
    $("a.vote").fadeOut(150, function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
<% end %>
```

This `.js.erb` will be called each time you hit the `vote` action with Ajax. It will perform functionality which will directly affect your pre-loaded page

---

**[.increment!](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!)**

Something to make your code DRYer:

```
unless cookies[params[:story_id]]
    @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
    @story.increment!(:rating)

    cookies[params[:story_id]] = true
end
```